# How to save input text as bitmap in as3? Can anyone please tell me why this code is not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

1.How to save input text as bitmap in as3? Can anyone please tell me why this   code is not working?

Some class files are imported here

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
```

Code starts here

```
var bitmapdata: BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200);
bitmapdata.draw(txt);

var xmv: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
xmv.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapdata);
xmv.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 300);
xmv.graphics.endFill();

var jpgEncoder: JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click)    

function click(e:MouseEvent) 
{
    var imgByteData: ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapdata);
    var file = new FileReference();
    file.save(imgByteData, "Image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem though? Did you get an error? Try setting a colour for the bitmapdata. Like `var bitmapdata : BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, false, 0x5500AA );` cos maybe your bitmap and text are same colour so you see nothing?? Also is `draw(txt);` drawing a Sprite / MovieClip called **txt** right? You can't draw a textfield (if I'm not mistaken) only the container of that text object. Is the bitmapdata linked to a bitmap? Did you try to encode the bitmap instead..

Comment: Please declaration the type.
`var file:FileReference = new FileReference();`
and `function click(e:MouseEvent) : void`

Comment: No, I didn't get any error. That's why I couldn't figure out anything. I tried what you have suggested. The problem is with  draw(txt); After I converted the textfield into a movieClip and executed the code, it displayed the text. So the problem is with setting a color for the bitmapdata. How can I do it?

Comment: @PiyumiSH Your code looks fine. What do you mean by : "this code is not working" ? After clicking the `save` button or movie clip, you should get the save dialog to save your image. Did you get that at least ?

Comment: Yes, I did get the save dialog to save the image. The image is saved. But without the text value in 'txt'. It is only showing the movieClip.

Comment: Are you adding `xmv` clip to stage? Do you see the text?

Comment: No I do not see the text. That is exactly the problem here

Comment: @PiyumiSH `xmv` has nothing to do with all that, you can even remove that part of code. Verify that your text field is not empty and that its color is not white, you should see the text in the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your kind responses! I appreciate it a lot. There hasn't really been any issue with the code. After I replaced the 'txt' input box with a new one, it functioned properly. So the problem might have been with some of the changes I've made unknowingly to the input box. I even customized the code for user input to be displayed as bitmap. Thanx again!